# java web copiar imagen en File WebContent

Tags: java, zk

Soy un poco nuevo en java estoy creando una pequeña pagina donde recibo imagenes en base64, las descodifigo y las publico para que sean publicas por url.
Para eso existe una carpeta  /webContent/img pero me da un error

```
@Path("/get")
public class ServiceGet extends HttpServlet {

  @GET
  @Path("/courses")
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public String courses() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("//home/luiggi/Documentos/eclipse/fotos/EDUARDO_0.jpg");
    FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    imageInFile.read(imageData);
    String imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);

    byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(imageDataString);
    File f = new File("../../WebContent/img/water-drop-after-convert.jpg");
    FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(f);
    imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
    imageOutFile.close();

    return "1";
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>apiface_v1</display-name>
    <listener>
        <description>       Used to cleanup when a session is destroyed</description>
        <display-name>ZK Session cleaner</display-name>
        <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>mi.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>   The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
          <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>   The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: A parte de tu código es fundamental que añadas la traza del error y además nos comentes el error en si mismo, con lo que has mandado no se sabe que error se esta produciendo.

Comment: El error que indica es cuando quiere grabar en la ruta que se indica(no lo encuentra), estuve leyendo en foros y todos usan                              ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String path = context.getRealPath("/");                                                                   pero cuando copio y pego este codigo he importo las librerias mencionados sigue dando error en estas lineas.

Comment: Estoy viendo que has puesto ***File file = new File("//home/luiggi/Documentos/eclipse/fotos/EDUARDO_0.jpg");*** no tienes que poner **//** en Linux no es necesario, basta con la **/**

Comment: @Ipman1971 en linux va a ignorar el doble `/` y utilizará solo uno, lo comento de experiencia (inocentada) personal.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio tocayo. Por favor edita la pregunta para que agregues todo lo necesario para comprender y posiblemente reproducir tu problema. Te recomiendo dos cosas: 1) Reemplaza la imagen que muestra el contenido de tu archivo web.xml y por el contenido del archivo en texto. 2) Dices que hay un error, entonces por favor muéstranos el mensaje de error, stacktrace o cualquier cosa que dé una pista o luz sobre lo que esté sucediendo en tu código. Además, considera que cuando guardes imágenes en tu aplicación web, no es bueno que se guarde en la carpeta donde la app se encuentra.

Comment: Lo unico que deseo es que estas imagenes puedan ser consultadas por url en alguna parte del proyecto, este proyecto lo pondre en un servidor gratuito con Tomcat. Pero nose como hacer para que las imagenes puedan ser publicadas.  La idea era decodificar la imagen, la cual lo hago correctamente y si ejecuto localmente y pongo una ruta fisica en mi pc si la guarda, pero deseo que se guarden en el proyecto porque subire a un hosting.

Comment: El problema de guardarla en el proyecto es que si subes una nueva versión puede que pierdas las imágenes. Así sea un hosting externo, se puede solicitar el acceso a una carpeta externa al proyecto donde puedas subir las imágenes, o sino podrías subir las imágenes a un servidor diferente y que tu aplicación sirva de proxy para comunicarse con este nuevo servidor para proveer las imágenes.

Comment: Realmente nose como aria eso, actualmente lo que hice es un servicio restful con el metodo POST me envian en formato JSON una imagen en base64 la decodifico y la guardo en una ruta, y luego deberia darles la url para que puedan consultar esta imagen.

Comment: Por favor ten en cuenta que hay una opción **editar** debajo del contenido de la pregunta. Selecciona dicha opción para que puedas editar tu pregunta en lugar de agregar respuestas.

Comment: Gracias amigo por la ayuda.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]